How to show that $T^2$ is a contraction?
Let $E$ be the vector space $\mathcal{C}^1 ([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert _ {\mathcal{C}^1}$ defined as,
$$\lVert f \rVert _ {\mathcal{C}^1} := \lVert f \rVert _ {\infty} + \lVert f' \rVert _ {\infty}$$
We consider the following mapping $T : E \longrightarrow E$ such that,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
   \forall f \in E, \quad T(f)~:~[0,1] & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
   x & \longmapsto & 1+ \int_0^x f(t-t^2)~dt
  \end{array}
  $$
Show that $T^2$ is a contraction.
Here's what I did :
Let $(f,g) \in E^2$ and $x \in [0,1].$ We have,
\begin{align}
\left|T^2(f)(x)-T^2(g)(x)\right|&= \left| 1+\int_0^x \left( 1+ \int_0^{s-s^2} f(t-t^2)~dt \right)ds - \left( 1 + \int_0^x \left( 1 +\int_0^{s-s^2} g(t-t^2)~dt \right)ds  \right)\right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^x \int_0^{s-s^2} f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)~dtds \right| \\
&\leq \int_0^x \int_0^{s-s^2} \left| f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2) \right|~dtds \\
&\leq \int_0^x \int_0^{s-s^2} \lVert f-g \rVert _ {\infty}~dtds \quad \text{(we have $t-t^2 \leq 1/4,~\forall t \in [0,1]$)} \\
&= \frac{3x^2-2x^3}{6}\lVert f-g \rVert _ {\infty}
\end{align}
We can deduce from the last inequality that $\left\lVert T^2(f) - T^2(g) \right\rVert _ {\infty} \leq \frac{1}{6}\lVert f-g \rVert _ {\infty}$.
For the next step, we have,
\begin{align}
\left|\left( T^2(f)(x)-T^2(g)(x) \right)'\right|&=\left| \frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_0^x \int_0^{s-s^2} f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)~dtds \right) \right| \\
&=\left| \int_0^{x-x^2} f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)~dt  \right|
\end{align}
Let $h(t)=f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)$ for $t \in [0,x-x^2] \subseteq [0,1/4]$. The MVT assures us that for every $t \in [0,x-x^2]$, it exists $\xi \in ]0,x-x^2[$ such that
$$h(t)=(t-0)h'(\xi)+h(0)$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\left|\left( T^2(f)(x)-T^2(g)(x) \right)'\right|&\leq  \int_0^{x-x^2} \left| h(t) \right|~dt \\
&\leq  \int_0^{x-x^2} t\left| h'(\xi) \right|~dt + \left| h(0) \right| \int_0^{x-x^2}~dt \\
&\leq \int_0^{x-x^2} t \left| 1-2\xi \right|  \lVert \left( f-g \right)' \rVert _ {\infty} ~dt + \left| h(0) \right| \int_0^{x-x^2}~dt \\
&\leq \lVert \left( f-g \right)' \rVert _ {\infty} \int_0^{x-x^2} t ~dt + \left( x-x^2 \right) \left| h(0) \right| \\
&\leq \frac{ \left( x-x^2 \right) ^2}{2} \lVert \left( f-g \right)' \rVert _ {\infty} + \left( x-x^2 \right)\left| h(0) \right|
\end{align}
Which gives us the inequality $\left\lVert \left( T^2(f) - T^2(g) \right)' \right\rVert _ {\infty} \leq \frac{1}{32}\lVert \left( f-g \right)' \rVert _ {\infty} +  \frac{1}{4} \left| h(0)\right|$ and,
$$\left\lVert T^2(f) - T^2(g) \right\rVert _ {\mathcal{C}^1} \leq \frac{1}{6} \left\lVert f-g \right\rVert _ {\mathcal{C}^1} + \frac{1}{4} \left| h(0) \right|$$
The goal is  not so far away but I have no idea how to remove the constant $\left| h(0) \right|$. Any help is appreciated! If I made mistakes or should have detailled more, feel free to tell me.

$\xi$ is not a constant and you cannot pull it out of the integral.

@geetha290krm You are right thank you! I corrected it.

Don't think your expression for $T^2$ is correct. You need $s-s^2$ as the upper bound of the inner integral.

@Wei You are right, I've remade the calculations and edited the page.

No need to bring $f'$ and $g'$ into this.
\begin{align}
\left|\left( T^2(f)(x)-T^2(g)(x) \right)'\right|&=\left| \frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_0^x \int_0^{s-s^2} f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)~dtds \right) \right| \\
&=\left| \int_0^{x-x^2} f(t-t^2)-g(t-t^2)~dt  \right| \\
&\leq (x-x^2)\lVert f-g \rVert _ {\infty} \\
&\leq \frac14\lVert f-g \rVert _ {\infty}.
\end{align}
So $$\lVert T^2(f)-T^2(g) \rVert_{\mathcal C^1}\leq \left( \frac16+\frac14 \right)\lVert f-g \rVert_\infty \leq \frac5{12}\lVert f-g \rVert_{\mathcal C^1}$$
and the constant $\frac5{12}$ can be made a bit smaller by maximising the sum of the two estimates instead of summing their maximisers.

Thank you very much ! I don't know why I was so obstinated with $\left\lVert f'-g' \right\rVert _{\infty}$
